# SAPUI5 extend method to create object with constructor arguments

Tags: typescript, sapui5

After messing with SAPUI5 for a while to get typescript class to work as SAPUI5 controller, I thought of asking for help from the community. I am trying to use typescript classes as SAPUI5 controller. I have got the basic class working but if I want to create a class with a constructor with arguments, my arguments are always getting set to undefined and I just can't figure it out how to resolve it properly or by nice hack not just hack :). Please have a look at the code below and suggest me what can be done to achieve this.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "worklist/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
    // Insert your used ui5 elements here to get them loaded
], (Controller: worklist.controller.BaseController, JSONModel: any) => {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("worklist.controller.View1", {
        constructor: function (json: any) {
            Controller.apply(this, JSONModel);
        }
    });
});

namespace worklist.controller {

    export class View1 extends worklist.controller.BaseController {
        constructor(json: any) {
            super();
        }
        onInit(): void {
            console.clear();
            console.info("name initialized");
        }

        onBeforeRendering(): void {
            console.info("name onBeforeRendering");
        }

        onAfterRendering(): void {
            const router = this.getRouter();
            console.info("name onAfterRendering");
        }

        onExit(): void {
            console.info("name onExit");
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above as you can see that my View1 constructor takes jsson as an argument. I am trying or want to pass JSONModel to that argument but having some hard time. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the method "appply" receive an array for its second parameter. So please user it in the following way.

```
 Controller.apply(this, [JSONModel]);
```

Comment: Please add some context to this answer. As its currently written, its not clear what your suggestion is.